# Why are my background-image not displaying

Tags: html, css, github-pages

I have an issue, my background-images are not displaying after I host my website with github pages

Link to repo: https://github.com/eugenemoringa/advanced-portfolio
Link to live page: https://eugenemoringa.github.io/advanced-portfolio/

Comment: Hi smart Fleek you have provided wrong image path in css therefore its not loading. Please correct the image path. For example background-image: url("../../carsimage.jpg"); I tried this and it was working fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

In your css files, when linking a image for the background image, you have to include `./` before the url.

This is what you have done

```
 background-image: url("/carsimage.jpg");
```

This is what you should do:

```
background-image:url("./carsimage.jpg");
```

Do this for all your background-image lines in your css files and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Use `../../` instead of `/` or `./` on `background`

```
header {
    background-image: url(../../carsimage.jpg);
}
```